# Mysqli query and select db warnings

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have this code and my browser is giving me warnings.  The code is here:

```
47  mysqli_select_db($database_connHotel, $connHotel);
48  $Result1 = mysqli_query($insertSQL, $connHotel) or die(mysqli_error($connHotel));
```

The warnings are here:

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/add_user.php on line 47

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/add_user.php on line 48
```

I dont understand the warnings and need help with how I fix it for a project due by the end of the week.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: mysqli_select_db($database_connHotel, $connHotel); - is your connHotel the name of your database nad $database_connhotel is your connection?

Comment: Which editor are you using that it copies the line numbers as well?

Comment: No hotelbooking is my database

Comment: Does your $database_connHotel or $connHotel variables have any quotes in them.?

Comment: You can specify the database name in the `mysqli` constructor / `mysqli_connect()`. I suggest you spend some time in the manual familiarising yourself with the *mysqli* extension methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the other way around for both of the functions, MySQL connection object is the first variable:

```
mysqli_select_db($connHotel, $database_connHotel);
```

Also,

```
mysqli_query($connHotel, $insertSQL)
```

**Reference:**
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

*`*mysql_* functions are not just converted to mysqli_* functions just by placing an 'i' at the end. Most of them have different set of parameters, please try having a brief search before using mysqli_* functions.`*

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

**link**

```
A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect().
```

**dbname**

```
The database name.
```

So use like this `mysqli_select_db($connHotel, $database_connHotel);`